# How do margins on Flexbox children affect their calculated width?

Tags: css, margin, flexbox

In exploring the use of Flexbox, I ran across something that I found to be a little odd.  If I toss three children with a horizontal margin of 10px into a Flexbox container, each with a flex value of 1, each child is of equal width, which is great.  But if I have two children, one of which having a flex value of 2, it's not quite a 2/3rds-1/3rd split.  If I remove the margin, however, it is a 2/3rds-1/3rd split, which is desired.

Here's some example code:

```
<div class = "flexbox">
    <div class = "flex" style = "background-color: red;">1/3</div>
    <div class = "flex" style = "background-color: green;">1/3</div>
    <div class = "flex" style = "background-color: blue;">1/3</div>
</div>
<div class = "flexbox">
    <div class = "flex double" style = "background-color: yellow;">2/3</div>
    <div class = "flex"  style = "background-color: purple;">1/3</div>
</div>
<style>
    .flexbox
    {
        display: flex;
    }

    .flexbox .flex
    {
        flex: 1;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

    .flexbox .flex.double
    {
        flex: 2;
    }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52fKh/

I'm not really grasping how the widths are being calculated in the second Flexbox.  Can anyone shed some light on that, and possibly offer a workaround so that the two Flexboxes line up?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract the margin space from your total possible width, then divide appropriately.

Take this JS Fiddle for example, where I have limited your flexbox class width to 600PX for demonstration...

http://jsfiddle.net/52fKh/2/

```
.flexbox
{
    display: flex;
    width: 600px;
}
```

In the case of your `flex: 2;` example...

Both of the two div's have a 10px left and right margin, that's 20px per div, 2 div's means 40px total margin space.

600-40 = 560

560/3 = 186.666666667

186.6666667 * 2 = 373.333333333

If you take a look at inspect element, you will see the width of your `flex: 2;` div to be 373PX.

---

To summarize, it is calculating the width based on the actual width of the div, not including the margin space.  Evaluate the margin space first, then what is left will mathematically add up.

Comment: I suspected that was the case, but I was neglecting to note that 60px are going toward the margins on the first group, and 40px off of the second.  Are you aware of any "box-sizing" style support for getting Flexbox to proportionally size and include the margins?

Comment: Well, the first thing I can say is that it is typical when designing columns like this to make sure there is no left side margin on the first child, and no right side margin on the last child.  That will make the math line up a little closer to what you expect, only 3 pixels off in the case of your flex: 2; example.  I don't know of any box-sizing type control for flexbox.